# Resources to learn NLP

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, natural-language-processing

I am an undergraduate student in mathematics. I have a fair bit of experience with deep learning in computer vision research and am willing to dabble into NLP. I hope that things won't be very disjointed and some of the knowledge can be transferred.

I wanted to know if y'all can recommend some YouTube playlists that start from scratch as far as NLP is concerned, and then gets pretty deep into the subject. I would also like it to have a research-oriented flavor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I like [The Stanford CS224N 2021 YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rOSH4v6133s9LFPRHjEmbmJ),
which focuses on deep learning models for NLP (but many things changed since 2021, esp. LLMs). For a pre-deep-learning NLP courses, I like:

- [Natural Language Processing by Michael Collins, Columbia University (Coursera, 2012 or 2013)](https://www.bilibili.com/video/av29608234/)
- [Dan Jurafsky & Chris-Manning: Natural Language Processing (Coursera, 2012)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rOFZnDyrlW3-nI7tMLtmiJZ)